AWS TextExtractor can handle any PDF formated file?
I am trying to analyze a PDF using Amazon Textract, but I got this "400 Bad Request", "Request has unsupported document format"
As far as I can see, Amazon TextExtractor can handle pdf files with 11 pages max, so I handle to split it in case it has more than 11 pages.
Also I do validate that the mime type is a PDF for sure and it's size.
The data extracted should be sabe into a field called 'extracted_data' with other data as You can see.
Let's see some code:
Upload pdf file blade:
<x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header">
    <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200 leading-tight">{{ __('messages.upload_operator_data') }}</h2>
</x-slot>
<div class="py-12">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 shadow-md p-6 lg:p-8 sm:rounded-lg">
            @if (session('success'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    {{ session('success') }}
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    URL do Arquivo: {{ session('file') }}
                </div>
                @if (session('downloadLinks'))
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        Arquivos PDF Divididos:
                        <ul>
                            @foreach (session('downloadLinks') as $link)
                                <li><a href="{{ $link }}" target="_blank">Download {{ $loop->index + 1 }}</a></li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif
            @endif

            <form action="{{ route('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                @method('POST')
                <div class="mb-6">
                    <label class="form-control w-full max-w-xs">
                        <div class="label">
                            <span class="label-text">{{ __('messages.operator_name') }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required class="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" />
                    </label>
                </div>
                @error('name')
                <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
                <div class="mb-6">
                    <label class="form-control w-full max-w-xs">
                        <div class="label">
                            <span class="label-text">{{ __('messages.upload_logo') }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="file" name="logo" class="file-input file-input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" />
                    </label>
                </div>
                @error('logo')
                <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
                <div class="mb-6">
                    <label class="form-control w-full max-w-xs">
                        <div class="label">
                            <span class="label-text">{{ __('messages.select_file') }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="file" name="file" class="file-input file-input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" required />
                    </label>
                </div>
                @error('file')
                <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
                <div class="mb-6">
                    <label class="form-control w-full max-w-xs">
                        <div class="label">
                            <span class="label-text">{{ __('messages.validity') }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="date" name="validity" id="validity" required class="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" />
                    </label>
                </div>
                @error('validity')
                <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
                <hr class="w-48 h-1 mx-auto my-4 bg-gray-100 border-0 rounded md:my-10 dark:bg-gray-700">
                <button class="btn btn-primary text-white">
                    {{ __('messages.send') }}
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

UploadController.php
<?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers\Super;

   use Aws\Textract\TextractClient;
   use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use App\Models\Operator;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
   use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
   use setasign\Fpdi\PdfReader;

   class UploadController extends Controller
   {
    public function uploadFile(Request $request)
  {
    $request->validate([
        'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:2048',
        'validity' => 'required|date',
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'logo' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    // Upload do arquivo PDF
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $path = $file->store('pdf_tabelas_precos', 's3');

    // URL do arquivo PDF armazenado no S3
    $urlFile = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path);

    // Upload do logo, se fornecido
    $logoPath = null;
    if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
        $logo = $request->file('logo');
        $logoPath = $logo->store('logos', 's3');
        $urlLogo = Storage::disk('s3')->url($logoPath);
    }

    // Processar o arquivo com Textract
    $extractedData = $this->processTextract($path);

    // Salvar detalhes no banco de dados
    $operator = new Operator();
    $operator->name = $request->input('name');
    $operator->validity = $request->input('validity');
    $operator->url = $urlLogo ?? '';
    $operator->url_file = $urlFile;
    $operator->extracted_data = json_encode($extractedData);
    $operator->save();

    // Retornar links de download dos arquivos divididos
    return back()->with('success', 'Arquivo enviado e processado com sucesso!')
        ->with('file', $urlFile);
}

protected function processTextract($s3FilePath)
{
    // Baixar o arquivo do S3 para um caminho local temporário
    $fileContent = Storage::disk('s3')->get($s3FilePath);
    $localPath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'pdf_') . '.pdf';
    file_put_contents($localPath, $fileContent);

    // Verificar se o arquivo é um PDF válido
    if (mime_content_type($localPath) !== 'application/pdf') {
        unlink($localPath); // Remover o arquivo local temporário
        throw new \Exception('O arquivo não é um PDF válido.');
    }

    $textractClient = new TextractClient([
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        ],
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT'),
    ]);

    try {
        $result = $textractClient->analyzeDocument([
            'Document' => [
                'Bytes' => file_get_contents($localPath),
            ],
            'FeatureTypes' => ['TABLES', 'FORMS'],
        ]);

        // Remover o arquivo local temporário
        unlink($localPath);

        return $result;
    } catch (AwsException $e) {
        // Remover o arquivo local temporário em caso de erro
        unlink($localPath);
        return $e->getMessage(); // Log the error or handle it appropriately
    }
}

protected function splitPdf($s3FilePath, $maxPages = 11)
{
    // Baixar o arquivo do S3 como string
    $fileContent = Storage::disk('s3')->get($s3FilePath);

    // Criar um caminho temporário para o arquivo local
    $localPath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'pdf_') . '.pdf';

    // Escrever o conteúdo do arquivo no caminho temporário
    file_put_contents($localPath, $fileContent);

    // Verificar se o arquivo foi escrito corretamente
    if (!file_exists($localPath) || !filesize($localPath)) {
        throw new \Exception('Falha ao baixar o arquivo do S3.');
    }

    // Processar o arquivo com FPDI
    $pdf = new Fpdi();
    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($localPath);
    $splitFiles = [];
    $downloadLinks = [];

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pageCount; $i += $maxPages) {
        $outputFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'split_') . '.pdf';
        $splitPdf = new Fpdi(); // Nova instância para cada iteração
        $splitPdf->setSourceFile($localPath); // Definir o arquivo de origem

        for ($j = $i; $j < $i + $maxPages && $j <= $pageCount; $j++) {
            $splitPdf->AddPage();
            $splitPdf->useTemplate($splitPdf->importPage($j));
        }

        $splitPdf->Output($outputFile, 'F');
        $splitFiles[] = $outputFile;

        // Salvar o arquivo no S3 e obter o link de download
        $s3Path = 'pdf_divididos/' . basename($outputFile);
        Storage::disk('s3')->put($s3Path, file_get_contents($outputFile));
        $downloadLinks[] = Storage::disk('s3')->url($s3Path);
    }

    // Remover o arquivo local temporário
    unlink($localPath);

    return [$splitFiles, $downloadLinks];
   }
 }

The error message that appears at the extracted_data filed is:
"Error executing \"AnalyzeDocument\" on \"https://textract.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://textract.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n{\"__type\":\"UnsupportedDocumentException\",\"Message\":\"Request has unsupported document format\"}\n UnsupportedDocumentException (client): Request has unsupported document format - {\"__type\":\"UnsupportedDocumentException\",\"Message\":\"Request has unsupported document format\"}"


Is the blade code related to the text extraction problem in any way, or is it just a way to upload a document for you to process?

It is just s way to upload a document

Many chapters of PoC or GTFO by Manul Laphroaig cover PDF polyglots. The books are just submitted hobbyist white papers and I now know too much about PDF. Good fun technical read, would recommended. Generally, it is a very forgiving format, but because of the variation, I wouldn't be surprised if your splitting process created a situation AWS can't handle. You could try a two-page empty PDF, split it into max of 1 page, and then see if that submits correctly. If it doesn't, but the two page document works, then you know it's an encoding issue. You can then get a hex dump of those PDFs and add them here.

A sample https://www.alchemistowl.org/pocorgtfo/pocorgtfo08.pdf
